# Exact match faceting search on SOLR

Tags: solr, solr4

I am usiing solr 4.

My SOLR gives the following faceting results:

- test model (12)
- priority test model (10)

When I select to show the faceting results on "test model", it also gives me back the results for "priority test model". It seems it does a full test search for facets. Is there any way I force a exact match for my faceting search in SOLR?

Comment: What is the field type you're faceting and filtering on?

Comment: @MatsLindh just CharField

Answer (score 0):

You need to use " in order to have exact match. So your query should be fq=`<field_name> : "<value>"`

Comment: So you mean instead of using `selected_facets=<fieldname_exact>:<value>`, I should use `fq = <field_name>:<value>` when I build my search query url, right? I will try it. Sorry for the late reply.